# Запятая в причастном-деепричастном обороте

Tags: деепричастный-оборот, причастный-оборот

Даже луна, движущаяся по небосводу(,) не причиняя никому вреда, осмеивалась множеством людей.
Нужна ли запятая в скобках?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению, нужна, сравните:

> "Дом его всегда был полон гостями, готовыми тешить его барскую
> праздность (как?), разделяя шумные, а иногда буйные его увеселения "
> (Пушкин).

В предложении слишком много запятых, оно получается двусмысленным. Можно изменить его так:

> Даже луна, движущаяся по небосводу и не причиняющая никому вреда, осмеивалась множеством людей.

Comment: Думается мне, что "непричиняющая" пишется с "не" раздельно.

Comment: А после "к сожалению" запятая не нужна?

Comment: **К сожалению, нужна, сравните...** Только никак не могу понять, почему именно  "к сожалению".